which versions of Solana SDK and Anchor are compatible with the stable toolchain.?
which versions of Solana SDK and Anchor are compatible with the stable toolchain.? It appears that the current nightly toolchain you are using (nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) does not support the bpfel-unknown-unknown target, which is necessary for building Solana programs!! missing the required target for building Solana programs, which is bpfel-unknown-unknown. Thank you

You'll need to install the Solana toolsuite, which contains the compiler which can target bpfel-unknown-unknown.
After you follow the instructions at https://solana.com/docs/intro/installation#install-the-solana-cli, you should be able to run cargo build-bpf or cargo build-sbf
